# Using template on windows form controls

Tags: templates

```
    public static T newitem<T>(Form Control, int Left, int Top, string Text = "", bool Visible = true) where T : new()
    {
        T a = new T();
        a.Left = Left;
        a.Top = Top;
        a.Text = Text;
        a.Visible = Visible;
        Control.Controls.Add(a);
        return a;
    }
```

I would like to write a function that adds any windows form control to my form. When I try to reach a.xxx I get an error.
Error: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Left' and no extension method 'Left' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional constraint, where `T : Control` since you can only add controls to a form.  This constrains `T` to be of type `Control` which ensures that the `Left` property is available (it's [defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.left.aspx) on control)